# how to use geonames web servics in android apps

Tags: android, web-services, geonames

I want to use geonames web services in my android app just for learning . so I follow [this sample](http://mobiforge.com/design-development/consuming-json-services-android-apps)

but in result I get this meaasge :

> {"status":{"message":"Please add a username to each call in order for
>   geonames to be able to identify the calling application and count the
>   credits usage.","value":10}}

and then I find out that I have to register in GeoNames site .so I sign up but nothing happened. for the last step : how can I show this registration in my code??

Answer (score 1):

When you go to your activation link there is an "enable" link down in the page, near the bug icon and above menu. Click it to enable your acount.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass username ..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    style: "medium",
                    maxRows: 10,
                    featureClass: "P",
                    continentCode: ["NA","SA","EU"],
                    q: request.term,
                    username: "demo"
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    if( typeof(data.status) != 'undefined' ){ //An error occured
                        var errorObject = data;
                        //Now we have access to errorObject.status, errorObject.status.message and so on
                        //Let's do something with the error object
                        return; //Stop parsing function
                    } 
                    response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryCode,
                            value: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryCode,
                            lat: item.lat,
                            lng: item.lng
                        }
                    }));
                },
            });
        },
        //Start Search after user types...
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            // Set Location for map
            $( '#lat' ).val( ui.item.lat );
            $( '#lng' ).val( ui.item.lng );
        },
        close: function() {
            //UI plugin not removing loading gif, lets force it
            $( '#city' ).removeClass( "ui-autocomplete-loading" );
        },
    });
  });
```